# Generate XSD with annotation and documentation from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, documentation, generate

I have found some tools to generate XSD files from XML files.
For example https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

I have also found some ways of using XSLT to create HTML Documentation such as the xs3p stylesheet, and im using [Saxonica](https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/) to execute that. But at the moment i have to add the annotations myself to the XSD.

From [xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/](https://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/)

> xs3p is a schema documentation generator. Basically, it is an XSLT
> stylesheet that will generate an XHTML document from an XSD schema.

My question is, is it possible to get the Annotations and Documentation from XML somehow?

So that is, can i somehow write something in my XML File that will be translated into.

```
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="ItemNo">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Item number (table.column))</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: (a) You say that you've *found some tools to generate XSD files from XML files*, but never say what those tools are.  (b) You tag your question as pertaining to XSLT, but you show no XSLT attempt.  You should remedy one or both of those deficiencies in order for anyone to help you here.

Comment: Done, thx for the input

Comment: Does the XML actually contain this information?  If not, how would any tool know what to add in the Annotations and Documentation?

Comment: I also need a tool that generate XSD  documentation using <annotation> <documentation>  inside the XSD as above. I try [XSDDOC](http://xframe.sourceforge.net/xsddoc/index.html) but It generate a page like Javadoc style. However I want a single page documentation, XS3P does not include <documentation> informations. Is there anybody knowing another tool please ?